# Local invertibility of function $F$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Consider the following system of equations:
> $$\begin{cases}xz^3+y^2w^3=1\\
> 2xy^3+w^2z=0\end{cases}$$
> Show that in a neighborhood of $(0,1,0,1)$, it's possible to define $x,y$ as functions of $z,w$. Moreover, show that $F(z,w)=(x(z,w),y(z,w))$ is invertible in a neighborhood of $(0,1)$.

I've defined $f:\mathbb{R^4} \to \mathbb{R^2}$; $f(x,y,z,w)=(xz^3+y^2w^3, 2xy^3+w^2z)$, and I arrived at the conclusion that $\det(\frac{\partial f}{\partial (x,y)}) \neq 0$, so that by Implicit Function Theorem, there is $U \in N_{(0,1,0,1)}$ and $V \in N_{(0,1)}$ such that $f(x,y,z,w)=(1,0) \land (x,y,z,w) \in U \iff (z,w) \in V \land (x,y)=(x(z,w), y(z,w))$.
Now for the second part, I know that $$J_F(0,1)= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial z}  & \frac{\partial x}{\partial w} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial w} \end{pmatrix}_{(0,1)} $$ but I couldn't explicitly tell that this matrix has determinant different than zero. Any suggestions?

$\mathrm{EDIT}$:Writing that $xz^3+y^2w^3=1; 2xy^3+w^2z=0$ and taking the derivatives in order to $z$ and then in order to $w$, I found that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}(0,1,0,1)=-\frac{1}{2}$; $\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}(0,1,0,1)=0$; $\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}(0,1,0,1)=0$
$\frac{\partial y}{\partial w}(0,1,0,1)=-\frac{3}{2}$. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your evaluations of the partial derivatives  $x_z,x_w,y_z,y_w$ at $(0,1)$ are correct.

By the Inverse Function Theorem, $F$ is locally invertible in a neighborhood of $(0,1)$ as soon as we show that $\det(J_F(0,1))\not=0$.
By taking the derivatives of $xz^3+y^2w^3=1$ and $ 2xy^3+w^2z=0$ we find
$$\begin{cases} 
x_zz^3+3xz^2+2y y_z w^3=0\\
x_wz^3+2y y_ww^3+3y^2w^2=0\\
2x_zy^3+6xy^2y_z+w^2=0\\
2x_wy^3+6xy^2y_w+2wz=0
\end{cases}\stackrel{(0,1)}{\implies} 
\begin{cases} 
2y_z=0\\
2y_w+3=0\\
2x_z+1=0\\
2x_w=0
\end{cases}\implies \begin{cases} 
y_z=0\\
y_w=-3/2\\
x_z=-1/2\\
x_w=0
\end{cases}$$
Hence
$$J_F(0,1)= \begin{pmatrix} x_z  & x_w \\ y_z & y_w \end{pmatrix}_{(0,1)}
=\begin{pmatrix} -1/2  & 0 \\ 0 & -3/2 \end{pmatrix}\implies \det(J_F(0,1))=3/4\not=0.$$